# Angular directive nesting bizarrely broken when upgrading from 1.4.9 to 1.5.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Apologies for the vague title; I have yet to figure out exactly *what* is breaking after the upgrade. Possibly the nesting of directives or template issues?

(example images & links to CodePens below)

### Problem

I have a simple open source AngularJS library that generates a calendar. When using AngularJS 1.4.9 it works perfectly. But when I bump up to AngularJS 1.5.0 it breaks the layout in the most bizarre of ways.

No errors are thrown and all calendar days *are* generated in the DOM, however, all the days are output into a single week and all weeks are output into a single month (not even the first week or month either.. arghhh!).

### Research

I have read the [migration guide for 1.4 > 1.5](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-4-to-1-5) but didn't see anything that sounded related. I also read through the [1.5 changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#150-ennoblement-facilitation-2016-02-05) and the related rc changelogs; again nothing sounded related.

When I check the actual arrays of months/weeks/etc that are generated in JS everything looks great. If I remove the nested directives and simply have all the markup in a single template, the DOM output is correct (this is not a true solution since this would break certain functionality of the library).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

---

### Code & Demos

See the exact same code with the different versions of AngularJS (check Settings > JavaScript to see the linked libraries):

- 1.4.9 (working): https://codepen.io/benjamincharity/pen/BLYrqr?editors=1000
- 1.5.0 (broken): http://codepen.io/benjamincharity/pen/pEVVXV?editors=1000

**Again, the only difference is the version of AngularJS included.**

The directive that is being used is simply:

`<!-- This should generate a 30 day calendar starting with the current day -->
<bc-calendar class="bc-calendar--days"></bc-calendar>`

[image]

Comment: seems like it could be fixed with css `flex` adjustments. Why it would break though is strange if templates and css were the same

Comment: I don't believe that CSS can fix this. If you look at the generated DOM in the broken example you'll see that the actual DOM nesting is messed up. No weeks inside the first month (there should be 6). Then a few empty weeks inside the second month while all days are inside the second week. So strange..

Comment: ok..admit i didn't do a close comparison...only really looked at broken one

Comment: No worries.. I'm taking any idea at this point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly 100% an answer, but that specific library relies heavily on the `replace` directive flag, which has since been deprecated [see here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb). I downloaded the source and removed the replace flag on each directive, then with a few modifications to the css was able to achieve this.
[image: angular-json-calendar modification]

The css changes were on `.bc-calendar--days, .bc--calendar--days` `width : 50px; display: inline-flex;`.

Comment: That is very interesting.. I knew the flag was deprecated but according to the docs (and that commit) it won't actually be removed until 2.0, which this that library isn't built for anyway. I will definitely dig into this a bit.

Comment: @Benjamin it has been known for a long time to cause unpredictable issues though

Comment: True. I guess I'm just curious as to what change was made in 1.5.0 that truly broke it though.

Comment: Removing the 'replace' flag did in fact solve this as @charliebeckwith noted.   Still very curious as to what was broken on AngularJS v1.5.0 since it should not have been a breaking release.

Comment: I am as well. I ran into a similar issue migrating from 1.4->1.5 so just thought to see if it was the cause here too.